# How do I send the user their password in October CMS?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-user-plugin

I am using the User plugin on OctoberCMS and my site has a manual user activation (in which the administrator activates the user from the backend). After that, an email is sent to the registering front end user with the login information including a generated password which I have managed to do.

I have tried to put the password as a Twig variable like {{ password }} in the email template, but the password does not show up.

However there is another email sent to the administrator on user registration that has the same field and the password does show up.

Is it the built-in limitation of October CMS or is there something that I am missing out on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way whereby an external password generator is accessed via API and then entered into the user's password field programmatically.

The advantage is that the password can be sent and the password is also saved. With an advice to change the password of course.